# Can not authenticate form system tools

Tags: 12.04, gnome, authentication

Whenever I try to run a program from gnome, I get messages like

```
Authenticated is required to run the Gparted Partition Editor
```

The same goes for all programs that need root permission and I try to run from 'System tools' in my gnome-fallback.

However the same user can become root in gnome terminal with no problem (I added the user to sudoers). I must mention that I've changed the user's password after OS install, so I think I need to update something but don't know what. I appreciate your hints.

Comment: Hi alfish, can you please provide the Ubuntu version you are using and when you say the GUI ,do you mean pressing ALT, Pressing the SUPER button, pressing ALT+F2..

Comment: Sure. It is 12.04 64bit, and I use gnome-fallback. By GUI, I mean accsessing the classical gnome menu > System Tools using mouse.

Comment: This is the standard dialog box that's displayed when you start a program (like most "System Tools") that requires "root privileges")  and you have to enter your user login password for this authentication. This tried and tested security measure has recently been adopted in Windows as well. Do you mean you want to get rid of this standard Linux security feature? I'm afraid your only option might be switching to one of those distribution that allow users to login as root like Puppy Linux, etc.

Comment: Sadi, I want the authentication window to accept my password which it does in terminal. I know that it's a very good policy. That's one reason that I've left Windows years ago :)

Comment: We can narrow this down some if you open a termainl and run "gksudo", select "ls" as the program to run as root and see if it works.  Then, from another terminal run "gksu" in the same way.  Do they work?

Comment: mfisch. I can do gksudo in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (as root)

```
adduser <username> sudo
```